# How get the value of an object property that has been excluded from the bind

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have the following model:-

```
[MetadataType(typeof(TMSServer_Validation))]

    [Bind(Exclude = "TMSRack,ServerModel")]
    public partial class TMSServer 
    {


    }
```

and I have the following drop down inside my view:-

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.Server.TMSRack.DataCenterID, ((IEnumerable<TMS.Models.DataCenter>)ViewBag.DataCenters).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
        Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.Name), 
        Value = option.ID.ToString(),
        Selected = (Model.Server.TMSRack != null) && (option.ID == Model.Server.TMSRack.DataCenterID)
    }), "Choose...")
```

Then on my controller class I have the following :-

```
ViewBag.Racks = repository.getrelatedracks(Server.TMSRack.DataCenterID);
```

But since I have excluded the `TMSRack` navigation property (mainly to avoid over-posting attacks), so the `Server.TMSRack.DataCenterID` will always be `null`. And to get its value I wrote the following:-

```
ViewBag.Racks = repository.getrelatedracks(Int32.Parse(  Request.Form["Server.TMSRack.DataCenterID"]));
```

But I know that using `Request.Form` is not the right approach to follow, so my question is there a way to get the excluded property using more reliable way ?
Thanks

Comment: If you need it, why are you excluding it?

Comment: i am excluding it to aovid over-posting attacks, but i need this specific value the "server.tmsrack.datacenterid" .. so is my approach of using Request.Form considered fine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is going to assume `TMSServer` is a domain model.

With that in mind, this is the perfect example of when to use a view model.  By using a view model instead, you have complete control over how the properties are mapped from the view model to the domain model.  Something like:

```
public class RackViewModel
{
    public int DataCenterID
    // other Rack properties
}
```

Then either send a list of `RackViewModel` to your view, or create a view model that encompasses all of that, too:

```
public class ContainerViewModel
{
    public List<RackViewModel> Racks { get; set; }
    // other view-specific properties
}
```

Now, when you POST the data back, not only do you have complete control over what properties you want to bind to your view models, you also have complete control over the mapping that takes place from converting your view models to domain models.

The bottom-line is this: if your view accepts a view model that only allows the user to POST the data they should be allowed to POST, over-posting doesn't even exist.  Well-designed view models, or even making the distinction between a view model and an input model (i.e. a separate model that represents the data you want to bind back to in your action), eliminates over-posting entirely.

Over-posting only exists because you're not restricting the model binding process enough.  If you ask it to bind to a class that has 10 properties in it when you only need 3 you're allowing the user to potentially stuff data into those other 7 properties.

This is one reason why view models are so popular.  They allow you to narrow the scope of your view, whilst also narrowing the scope of the model binder.  That leaves you free to properly manage the process of mapping from your view model to your domain model, without introducing a vulnerability.

### Update

As you don't want to go the view model approach, your idea will work but you can do it slightly differently.  Something along the lines of:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeModel model, TMSRack rack)
```

Where:

1. `SomeModel` is the type of model you're decorating with `Bind(Exclude...)` (it's not obvious what type that is from your question.
2. `TMSRack` is the type I assume you want to bind to.

As `TMSRack` is defined in your main model anyway, as long as you're using the `Html.*` helpers, it will have the correct names generated for it on the form in order to bind straight back to it as a separate parameter on your action.  Then you can do whatever you want with it, without resorting to `Request.Form`.

Comment: i got your point , but the problem in using view Models is that i am going to create the whole model classes again, and the data annotations associated with them.so i took another approach of using the original model classes, but define and Exclude bind list . and even on some views i am using view models but they contains the original models inside them . such as public class ServerJoin
    {public TMSServer Server { get; set; }
    public Resource Resource { get; set; }
    public Technology Technology { get; set; }} . where the TMSServer & Resource & Technology are domain model class.

Comment: i can not understand your point , why i need to pass two models to my SomeAction ?

Comment: @johnG The first model is the one you're already passing, which is excluding the property you need.  The second one is the type that you're excluding and which also *contains* the value you want (`DataCenterID` in this case).  This will work because you're only preventing the model binder from binding a `TMSRack` that's contained in your main type, but that doesn't stop it from being bound separately.

Comment: @johnG You don't have to do it like this, but it saves you from having to use `Request.Form` and also parsing the value.  The model binder will do that all for you.  It's just a suggestion.

Comment: ok  got your point, but is using Request.form considered a bad approach. i know in this way i will be hard-coding the model properties names. but doing so on very limited number of properties  will be fine or not ?

Comment: @johnG It'll be fine, but it just seems to me like you're duplicating effort.  The whole purpose of the model binder is to stop you having to worry about using `Request.Form` or `FormCollection` or anything like that.  What you're doing is fine, but it's essentially the manual way of doing things.